# Permalink /%postname%/ doesn't work

Tags: permalinks

I changed the permalink structure of my site from `default` to `postname`, but this does not work: trying to access a post returns me the error 404.

Then I tried to try other types of permalinks, and everyone worked (except `/%postname%/`, of course). So I tried to create a custom permalink: `/index.php/%postname%/`. This works and I can not understand why.

I tried to change the theme and to set the structure `postname` and everything works perfectly. From what can be due to the error?

This is my `.htaccess` file:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```